# How to get JSON vars from PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a problem:

I have a JS function which sending data to php script, then PHP script returning JSON data from database QUERY and I want to get values returned from PHP script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--

    jQuery('#wysz2').submit(function() {


        var myData = {
            "rodzaj_konta": jQuery('#rodzaj_konta').val(),
            "miejscowosc": jQuery('#miejscowosc').val()
        };

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'http://somescript.php?action=results',
            type: 'GET',
            data: myData,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                jQuery('#loading').html('<p>loading...</p><img src="loading.gif" />'); //Loading image during the Ajax Request
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error: " + (errorThrown ? errorThrown : xhr.status));
            },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data) {

                alert(data);
            }


        });

        return false;

    });
    //-->​
</script>
```

The PHP script returning data in proper format using:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

When I'm trying to alert(data), I get always a null.

How to get this returned JSON data ?

EDITED:

It's strange, because I have changed sending method to POST.

PHP returning JSON:

```
[{"nazwa":"Test","nazwa_firmy":"Testowa","ulica":null,"numer_domy":"2A","numer_mieszkania":"11","kod_pocztowy":"00-189","miejscowosc":"Warszawa","telefon":"213-123-132","nip":"112-312-31-31","regon":"231232133","adres_www":"http:\/\/www.gogl.epl","rodzaj_uzytkownika":"serwis"}]
```

But my JQUERY AJAX Script still returning null.

So my script now looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                <!--

                    jQuery('#wysz2').submit(function() {




                    var myData = {
                       rodzaj_konta: jQuery('#rodzaj_konta').val(),
                        miejscowosc: jQuery('#miejscowosc').val()
                    };



                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: 'http://somedomain.com/skrypt.php?action=wyniki_wyszukiwania',
                        type: 'GET',
                        data: myData,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        jsonp: "jsoncallback",
                        beforeSend:  function() {
                            jQuery('#loading').html('<p>ładowanie...</p><img src="loading.gif" />');//Loading image during the Ajax Request
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("Error: " + (errorThrown ? errorThrown : xhr.status));
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                            console.log(data);
                        }

                    });

                    return false;

                });
                //-->
                </script>
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: show your json string with data

Comment: Try using the console and see if there are any errors, and start using console.log for debugging, **not** alerts.

Comment: The URL isn't returning valid JSON. `http://somescript.php` doesn't look right, if this has just been replaced for the question you should use sensible examples in the question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

you are constructing your variables while sending in a wrong way semicoluns for object names is not there according to definitions

try this

```
var myData = {
           rodzaj_konta: jQuery('#rodzaj_konta').val(),
            miejscowosc: jQuery('#miejscowosc').val()
        };
```

and while alerting your json data try

```
alert(JSON.stringify(your_json_obj));
```

Comment: I have updated my question, because it's so strange for me, why PHP return JSON, and script return null.

Answer (score 0):

Try to alert the object of the result...

Means if json in the format {"responseCode":"001","responseMsg":"success"}

Then alert data.responseCode

Answer (score 0):

In success of your ajax function try something like this 
     `var objParams1 = $.parseJSON(data);
     console.log(objParams1);
     alert(objParams1.Testowa)`